# I want to anchor tag on my dotnetnuke site and when any one click on that it redirect to another website with all user information bia url

Tags: dotnetnuke-5

I want to anchor tag on my dotnetnuke site and when any one click on that it redirect to another website with all user information bia url.

Answer (score 0):

Use the URL like this.
Suppose you have following details:
    firstname = "Bucky"
    lastname = "Roberts"
    age = 28

And the link you want to re-direct your user to will be:

```
www.example.com
```

Then put a `?` after your link like this:

```
www.example.com?
```

Then write your `firstname` like this:

```
www.example.com?firstname="Bucky"
```

Then write your `lastname` and `age` like this:

```
www.example.com?firstname="Bucky"&lastname="Roberts"&age=28
```

Then on `www.example.com`, suppose you have a PHP page, retrieve your parameters as:

```
$firstname = $_GET["firstname"];
$lastname = $_GET["lastname"];
$age = $_GET["age"];
```

Or if you have a Java Servlet or a JSP script, retrieve your parameters as:

```
String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
String lastname = request.getParameter("lastname");
int age = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("age"));
```

`request` is your `HttpServletRequest` instance.

Comment: Aditya                                                                I need it in .netnuke not in php. I am also a php developer. but don't know how to do in .netnuke